n-Selmer group of elliptic curve
Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve over number field and let $a,b$ be positive integers.
Then we have the following exact sequence : $$0 \rightarrow E[a] \rightarrow E[ab] \rightarrow E[b] \rightarrow 0.$$
Taking Galois cohomology, we obtain the exact sequence $$ \rightarrow H^1(K,E[a]) \rightarrow H^1(K,E[ab]) \rightarrow H^1(K,E[b])\rightarrow.$$
Let $Sel_n(E/K)$ denote the n-Selmer group of elliptic curve $E/K$.
Does $f$ induce a map $\bar{f} : Sel_a(E/K) \rightarrow Sel_{ab}(K)$?
Assume $c \in Sel_a(E/K)$ and $c_v$ comes from $P\in E(K_v)/{aE(K_v)}$.
I think that $(\bar{f}(c))_v$ comes from $bP$. Am I right?

It does. There's even an exact sequence $\mathrm{Sel}a \to \mathrm{Sel}{ab}\to \mathrm{Sel}b$. Moreover, if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then $\mathrm{Sel}{ab} = \mathrm{Sel}_a\times\mathrm{Sel}_b$. It's for this reason that people typically focus on $p^n$-Selmer groups.

@Mathmo123 Thank you for your help.
